# How do I parameterize a search for jsonb array contains?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have colA, which is a jsonb column with an array. Here are some sample rows:

```
["postgresql", "mysql", "elasticsearch"]
["python", "perl"]
```

I am trying to search for if the array has "postgresql" or "mysql":

`SELECT 'colA @> ANY (ARRAY ['["postgresql"]', '["mysql"]']::jsonb[])' FROM mytable`

That returns the first row. Now, since users will be passing data then I need to parameterize the queries:

`SELECT 'colA @> ANY (ARRAY ['[$1]', '[$2]']::jsonb[])' FROM mytable`

But I get:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "["
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may `cross join` the table with `jsonb_array_elements_text()` in the `from` clause which allows you to filter records  in the `where` clause based on the corresponding values obtained.

```
select t.id,j.* from mytable t cross join 
               jsonb_array_elements_text(cola) as j(val)
 where j.val  IN ( 'postgresql','mysql');
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fed5f11c0b88a89a3ba442e0707bf84e)